# Do anonymous struct change layout and padding?

Tags: c++

I am dealing with anonymous structs from a legacy interface. At run-time the fields get populated from an external source, example:

```
struct foo {
    union {
        struct {
            int a;
        };

        struct {
            int b;
            int c;
            int d;
        };
    };
};
```

The idea with the union is that depending on external factors, the legacy interface makes `foo` act as if it contained only struct 1 or 2. Anonymous unions in C++ are legal; anonymous structs are not. As far as I know, all an anonymous struct really does is make its members visible to the outerscope.

Do anonymous structs have any "visible effect" on the program or is it just nice for grouping related fields? That is, can I just make it `union { int a; int b; int c; int d; }` without having an observable difference from the previous code?

Comment: If you make it `union { int a; int b; int c; int d; }`, then `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` will all share the same address, and only one of them can be "active" at a time. On the other hand, your current code gives unique addresses to `b`, `c`, and `d`, so they can all be used simultaneously. `sizeof(foo)` should, barring any weird compiler, be equal to `sizeof(int) * 3`.

Comment: anonymous structs are not legal in c++???

Comment: Stop immediately touching that code and go study what `union`s are and how they work. There's potential to do apocalypse-level damage by doing the change you proposed.

Comment: @BЈовић "ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs" is pretty clear, IMO.

Comment: @MatteoItalia If there is a legal alternative I am looking for it. Do you like relying on compiler extensions to fix legacy cruft?

Comment: @user7995746: I like it way more than letting developers break perfectly working code they don't understand just because they feel bad that it's not 100% standard.

Comment: @user7995746 which paragraph in the standard says so?

Comment: Obviously, `union { int a; int b; int c; int d; }` is something very different than `union{struct { int a; };struct { int b,c,d }}`.Sure that you don't mean `struct{struct { int a; };struct { int b,c,d }}`?

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are radically different.

`union { int a; int b; int c; int d; }` has 4 members, only one of which can be active at a time. All 4 elements have the same size.

```
union {
    struct { int a; };
    struct { int b,c,d };
};
```

has 2 members, and they're *not* the same size.

Comment: I think you missed the first half of the question: does anonymous structs do weird stuff